# Facebook SDK - /{user-id}/friends returns zero friends

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-opengraph

my company is developing a mobile game with Unity,  we use the Unity FB SDK to get a list of friends using the app, we logged in with different test users (admin, developers, testers on the fb developer app page), which are friends on facebook, but we still get an empty list.

We also tried with the Graph API Explorer, and even if I have multiple friends, which are also app testers, I still get an empty list (image attached).

Here you can find debug information from graph explorer

```
==== Query
  curl -i -X GET \
   "https://graph.facebook.com/v13.0/me/friends?access_token=<access token sanitized>"
==== Access Token Info
  {
    "perms": [
      "user_friends",
      "public_profile",
      "basic_info"
    ],
    "user_id": 3963032267115258,
    "app_id": 352594886171268
  }
==== Parameters
- Query Parameters


  {}
- POST Parameters


  {}
==== Response
  {
    "data": [],
    "summary": {
      "total_count": 725
    },
    "__debug__": {
      "messages": [
        {
          "link": "https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0",
          "message": "Only friends who installed this app are returned in API v2.0 and higher. total_count in summary represents the total number of friends, including those who haven't installed the app.",
          "type": "info"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
==== Debug Information from Graph API Explorer
- https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%2Ffriends&version=v13.0
```

We use the user_friends permission, we also tried to get the app approved for advanced access (I don't know if we actually need it) but of course it was rejected because who tested the app couldn't get the friends list.

Note that we are trying to get only the list of friends who are also using our app, we know that now is not possible anymore to get the full list of facebook friends.

We don't know what else try, can someone help us please?

Comment: Did the other users also grant the `user_friends` permission? They _both_ need to grant it, the app user on whose behalf you are making the request, and the friend that is supposed to show up on the list.

Comment: Yes we did that, we also checked on Facebook->Settings->Security and login->Apps and Webiste, all accounts have "Friends list" among info they are sharing with the app. We are still not able to understand what's is going wrong.